# Devise undefined method 'registration_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Was working on my app and install and uninstall a couple gems and then suddenly the devise stuff stopped working and I can't figure out why.  I keep getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Recipes#index
undefined method `registration_path' for #<#<Class:0x00560876ed7ef0>:0x00560876f06430>
```

Its referring to my sign-up for and this block of code

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), validate: true) do |f| %>
                <%= devise_error_messages! %>
                <%= f.input :email, validate: true, required: true, placeholder: "Email", label: false %>
                <% if @minimum_password_length %>
                  <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
                <% end %>
                <%= f.input :password, autocomplete: "off", required: true, placeholder: "Password", label: false %>
                <%= f.input :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", required: true, placeholder: "Confirm Password", label: false %>
                <%= f.input :firstname, required: true, placeholder: "First Name", label: false %>
                <%= f.input :lastname, required: true, placeholder: "Last Name", label: false %>
                <%= f.input :displayname, validate: true, placeholder: "Display Name", label: false %>
                <div class="recaptcha">
                  <%= recaptcha_tags %>
                </div>
                <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
              <% end %>
```

In my routes.rb i have this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations', omniauth_callbacks: "callbacks" }
```

And this is the registrations controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

    def sign_up_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :displayname, 
                                     :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    def account_update_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :displayname,
                                     :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    def create
        if !verify_recaptcha
            flash.delete :recaptcha_error
            build_resource(sign_up_params)
            resource.valid?
            resource.errors.add(:base, "There was an error with the recaptcha code below. Please re-enter the code.")
            clean_up_passwords(resource)
            respond_with_navigational(resource) {render :new}
        else
            flash.delete :recaptcha_error
            super
        end
    end

    def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        '/pages/confirm_email'
    end
end
```

I have the devise stuff in the user model and controller that is standard and nothing changed with them but it stopped working.  Not sure how to fix this

Edit:  The rake route shows the registration path isnt in there for some reason:

```
                               Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                                                             Controller#Action
                          rails_admin          /admin                                                                  RailsAdmin::Engine
                     new_user_session GET      /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                devise/sessions#new
                         user_session POST     /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                devise/sessions#create
                 destroy_user_session DELETE   /users/sign_out(.:format)                                               devise/sessions#destroy
user_google_oauth2_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /users/auth/google_oauth2(.:format)                                     callbacks#passthru
 user_google_oauth2_omniauth_callback GET|POST /users/auth/google_oauth2/callback(.:format)                            callbacks#google_oauth2
     user_facebook_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /users/auth/facebook(.:format)                                          callbacks#passthru
      user_facebook_omniauth_callback GET|POST /users/auth/facebook/callback(.:format)                                 callbacks#facebook
                    new_user_password GET      /users/password/new(.:format)                                           devise/passwords#new
                   edit_user_password GET      /users/password/edit(.:format)                                          devise/passwords#edit
                        user_password PATCH    /users/password(.:format)                                               devise/passwords#update
                                      PUT      /users/password(.:format)                                               devise/passwords#update
                                      POST     /users/password(.:format)                                               devise/passwords#create
                new_user_confirmation GET      /users/confirmation/new(.:format)                                       devise/confirmations#new
                    user_confirmation GET      /users/confirmation(.:format)                                           devise/confirmations#show
                                      POST     /users/confirmation(.:format)                                           devise/confirmations#create
```

Ok so this error is baffling me.  I am using docker-compose for my development and ive rebuilt the containers and images.  Deleted everything and started over.  Something in signup settings of devise got messed up and not sure where to look to see if it is correct.  So when I go to: `localhost:8000/users/sign_in` Everything works fine and it goes to the devise sign-in page...but when I go to `localhost:8000/users/sign_up` It says `Couldn't find User with 'id'=sign_up`.  Its like the devise_for :users is being ignored for the sign-up stuff and not sure where to look for that cause thats all internal to the gem...I think

Comment: Use `rake routes` to see the routes for the application. If you model is user it should be `user_registration_path`.

Comment: when I run rake routes its not there for some reason...edited post to show all the devise routes

Comment: do you have `devise` installed ?

Comment: yes, it has all the other devise routes and i reran the install just to make sure

Comment: @DRing try restarting the server.

Comment: already did that

Comment: @DRing Restarting the server helped you??

Comment: No, still have the issue

Comment: Updated with more info...apparently its not using the devise routes for registration for some reason...its like just that part of the gem got destroyed or busted, but no matter what i do to try and reinstall it doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So after many hours of digging thru my code, comparing to my old code and googling every combination of devise and registration I could think.  I stumbled upon the problem and it was stupid...Somewhere in editing my User.rb model I accidently deleted :registable from the devise modules.  That is why it wasnt generating the registration routes.  So fixed my line of code from this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable,  :confirmable, 
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
       :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:google_oauth2, :facebook]
```

to This:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable, 
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
       :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:google_oauth2, :facebook]
```

Not sure where or how that got deleted but it did and cause it was in the middle of the block didnt notice as I was looking over my code

Answer (score 5):

Also try restarting the server.

I had `:registrable` in my User controller, yet kept getting the same error. Restarting the server helped me out.

Comment: Thanks for this. I didn't restart the server after generating User model and routes

Comment: No worries, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

I have spent almost the day on digging into this and found a silly mistake. While doing some other stuff in my devise model, i.e- Artist, I have mistakenly deleted the **registerable** from the code.

Changed the code from

```
devise :database_authenticatable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
```

to

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
```

Answer (score 1):

Re-run rails generate devise:view, then say 'y' for Overwrite the files.
this worked for me.